# How do I open a local file in Visual Studio Code on my Chromebook?

Tags: node.js

I want to open the local file /usr/share/applications/Xampp.desktop, but the open dialog does not show the usr directory at all, Nor does Nautilus file browser of the built in Files app.

How do I open this file in VSC?