How to open a folder in VS code on chromebook
I am a beginner of one month in python and i have been learning....but recently for some project purposes i tried to open a folder..but its simply not opening..i watched some youtube tutorials and google...as they said to go to files>open folder, but unlike in their case my screen shows something elseenter image description here.
I have veiwed all of the options in this screen and none of them take me to the storage of my chromebook
i even tried dragging and dropping but thats a no go too
Help would be appreciated
thank you
I wanted my folder to open so i can use different languages in it to create a project but i am unable to do so

seems to be dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67910392/11107541, and potentially https://stackoverflow.com/q/78557788/11107541

Just open a terminal, jump with cd PATH/TO/WORKSPACE in your workspace and open VSCode from command line with code . This will open VSCode in current directory as root directory.
or
simply run
code PATH/TO/WORKSPACE

or
Your image shows a screenshot from your file explorer, not VSCode. To open a folder, start VSCode and then go in the GUI of VSCode under Files -> Open Folder and navigate to your workspace and then clock 'OK'

I tried this..it did open the workspace but what next?
as for the last part
the image i sent is the one that opens after Files --> Open folder option..and then this is what opens......
thank you for answering.....and for any potential future help
